# Haskell: Filtering a list using a list of rules

Tags: haskell

So I've got a list of items (Recipes) that I want to filter based on a ruleset,

```
ruleset = [rule0, rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4]
```

where each rule is a function :: Recipe -> Bool. I want to apply these rules to each item in the list, and I've been doing so using the following function:

```
testRules :: Recipe -> Bool
testRules r = rule0 r && rule1 r && rule2 r && rule3 r && rule4 r
```

There must be a way to apply the array without explicitly saying "rule0 && rule1&& ..."

Does anyone know a way? I know that 'map' applies one function to a list.. And zipWith multiplies an array by an array.. There must be another function to perform this task!

I've also been thinking that maybe I can pass ruleset to testRules as a parameter and recursively go through the set of rules:

```
testRules (rule:rules) r = rule r && testRules rules
testRules [] r = True
```

However, I don't know how to provide the head of the function (testRules :: )

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `and`, which takes a list of `Bool` and return `True` iff all of them are `True`.

Then, using zipWith with application ($):

```
testRules :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
testRules :: and $ zipWith ($) ruleset (repeat r)
```

Comment: I don't think your second example does what you think it does. The `Applicative` instance for `[]` is the Cartesian product version (like the `Monad` instance), not the zippy version you get from the `newtype` wrapper `ZipList`.

Comment: You are completely right, I forgot that the instance for `[]` is not the zippy one.

Comment: You *can* use the [] Applicative instance for this too: and $ ruleset <*> [r].

Answer (score 11):

There's also the function `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` that can be used. This function checks if a predicate holds for all values of a list.

Only now, we're going to turn around things a bit, and let the predicate be 'is the result of this rule True when it is applied to x' and the list will contains the predicates.

You can express the predicate as `\rule -> rule x == True` but that's the same as `\rule -> rule x`, which is the same as `\rule -> rule $ x` which is the same as `($x)`. So this line of thought gives us the nice and short:

```
testRules :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
testRules rules x = all ($x) rules
```

This could be made pointfree by using `testRules = flip (all . flip ($))` but that's overdoing things a bit, I think.

Comment: I would make the `rules` the second argument, so you can get one less point: `testRules x = all ($x)`.

Comment: I just went by the idea of the question where the rules come first, and it also has the nice property of being a combinator on predicates `a -> Bool`.

Comment: Ah yes. It makes it easy to use as a filter predicate. Good point!

Answer (score 3):

Combining `and` with a list comprehension solves this nicely:

```
testRules :: [Recipe -> Bool] -> Recipe -> Bool
testRules ruleSet r = and [rule r | rule <- ruleSet]
```

Answer (score 2):

First that came to mind:

```
testRules :: Recipe -> [ Recipe -> Bool ] -> Bool
testRules r ruleset = and $ map (\rule -> rule r) ruleset
```

Comment: The compiler is giving me the following now: "Couldn't match expected type 'a0 -> Bool' with actual type '[b0]' in the return type of a call 'map'.  Probable cause: 'map' is applied to too many arguments"

Comment: I think you mean `and`, which you could write `\t -> and . map ($t)` or obscurely `all . flip id`

Comment: @thisIStheRUKUS My fault, haven't tested it before posting, now it should work

Comment: Yes, it could be shorter: `testRules r rs = and $ map ($ r) rs`

Comment: You should keep using composition to separate arguments from function. `and . map ($r) $ rs` or `(and . map ($r)) rs`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a lot of ways. I like a fold (with applicatives):

```
testRules = foldl1 (\f r -> (&&) <$> f <*> r) rules
```